# Mongoose Update doesn't return latest data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it just me or could I be doing something wrong.

I have the following code:

```
let post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate({'name':'Existing Name'},{'name':'My New Name'});
console.log(JSON.stringify(post,null,2));
```

The above code initiates the update and I can confirm that the update reflected in the MongoDB database however the returned post is still the old post and does not contain the result of the update.

Why is this so?

Comment: Use `returnNewDocument: true` inside the `options` part, as can be seen in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Mongoose you will need to set an optional 3rd parameter object property to  `{new: true}` as per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) like so:

```
let post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
   {'name':'Existing Name'}, 
   {'name':'My New Name'}, 
   {new: true}
);
```

Please also note:

> Mongoose's findOneAndUpdate() is slightly different from the MongoDB Node.js driver's findOneAndUpdate() because it returns the document itself, not a result object. As an alternative to the new option, you can also use the returnOriginal option. returnOriginal: false is equivalent to new: true. The returnOriginal option exists for consistency with the the MongoDB Node.js driver's findOneAndUpdate(), which has the same option.